# Coloring/Highlighting Text in sublime

Tags: sublimetext

I generally use Sublime as a **text editor** to keep my notes as I like the feel of sublime. 
I was wondering if there is a way I can choose to selectively color/highlight some of my texts (not the whole content). 
For the list of to-do things, this coloring can help me to differentiate the processed items in the list and pending items easily. Same for differentiating between important notes and non-important notes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could write your own syntax for it... take a look at other syntaxes.

In your case it would just be regex matching something like this presumably:

```
- not done
+ done
~ important
* not important
```

which would be pretty easy to manage.

The good thing about editing the syntaxes is that the results are immediately visible in the file, so you can see if what you did worked.